# Правильно ли тут употреблен дефис?

Tags: орфография

циклично открываются-закрываются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Правильно ли тут употреблен дефис?

ПРАВИЛЬНО. См. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97#pp97 :

> **§ 9…** Не являются однородными членами предложения и не разделяются запятой, а соединяются дефисом… парные сочетания антонимического
>   характера: *сформулировать вопросы-ответы; расширился экспорт-импорт;
>   условия купли-продажи; отмечать приход-расход; приём-выдача книг;
>   твёрдость-мягкость согласных; бегать вверх-вниз; двигаться
>   вперёд-назад…*